# Multiple dex files defined: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbqx

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-storage, dex

I am encountering a problem when I am trying to use the dependency

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
```

I have surfed the internet and I know this question was already addressed on how to remove redundant libraries like going into the CMD and executing the command `gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile`,,,,but when I have tried this command, I got the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

And now after adding the stacktrace option as stated, I got this new error stating

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput
DaemonGreeter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(
efaultDaemonStarter.java:152)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(D
faultDaemonStarter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon
DefaultDaemonConnector.java:208)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(Def
ultDaemonConnector.java:130)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.
ava:127)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.
ava:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.ja
a:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunt
meValidationAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunt
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRe
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRe
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute
CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute
CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoot
trap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.
ava:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.j
va:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I have even tried other ways like adding

```
android
{
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-wallet'
}
}
```

After doing so, The application started working but got a runtime error near Firebase recycler adapter(which was working properly earlier).

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.talarir.mapproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have to use Firebase storage, but I am stuck with this issue. :(

KINDLY HELP ME OUT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add multidex dependency too

Comment: @VivekMishra, Thanks for your quick response. I have added the line "multiDexEnabled true" in my gradle. Now everything is working FINE :D :)..Thanks a lot!